# Как в php обратиться к объекту данных JSON?

Tags: php, json

```
$json = '{"raw": [{"q": "ab6c5412-5c7f-489d-8d79-173ce632930e","a": "3f0bb0ea-fc31-4b49-86b5-337ca0cf86da"},{"q": "d337ecb3-b903-4664-94c1-16acf2c2e3bb","a": "f3d4933b-6af3-48a9-a836-0173bbbf6415"}],"answers": [{"q": "Какая сумма Вашей задолженности перед кредитными организациями в рублях?*","a": "Более 1 000 000 руб."},{"q": "Срок просрочки по кредитам?","a": "от 1 до 3 месяцев"}],"contacts": {"name": "Имя","email": "email@email.ru","phone": "89851234567"},"quiz": {"id": "600920a2de60d9004900edb9","name": "Генератор подарков"},"created": "2018-12-19T10:23:25.796Z","extra": {"href": "http://example.com","utm": {"source": "test_source","medium": "test_medium","name": "test_campaign","content": "test_content","term": "test_term"},"cookies": {"roistat_visit": "95852","roistat_marker": "example.com","roistat_marker_old": "example.com","roistat_call_tracking": "1","roistat_emailtracking_email": "null","_ga": "GA1.3.2016698540.1531763909"},"discount": 3,"discountType": "melting","discountCurrency": "₽","currency": "RUB","currencySymbol": "₽","notify": "now","ab": "A", (если включено A/B тестирование)"timezone": 5,"lang": "ru","referrer": "http://example.com""ip": "111.11.111.111"}"result": {"id": "OBq5B3FYI6","title": "Заголовок результата","cost": "1500","minCost": null,"maxCost": null}}';
```

Есть строка! Делаю интеграцию с marquiz. У них на сайте, есть пример https://help.marquiz.ru/article/518 Пробую сделать так же, но что-то не выходит. Пробовал преобразовать сначала в json, а потом декодировать. Ничего не получается, видимо совсем забыл как это делается.

Пробовал так, выдает "{".

```
$json = json_encode($json);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$answers = $json['answers'];
echo "<pre>";
        print_r($answers);
echo "</pre>";
```

Нужно вытащить объекты данных, а именно answers и contacts. Из answers вытащить массив коллекций объектов в цикл, а в contacts вытащить данные контактов. Прошу помочь вспомнить.

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode($json, 1));`

Comment: @InDevX NULL выдает.

Comment: Естественно, json не валидный в примере. И нет смысла кодировать чтобы потом декодировать....

Comment: @InDevX точно! Так самый прикол у них самих  на сайте он с ненужными вставками. Прошу прощения за мою невнимательность. Думал, что там правильно и не посмотрел. Там () в таких скобках текст и ещё запятой нет в 2х местах.